# Cannot require('ffi') in my office javascript add-in custom functions

Tags: javascript, office-js, ffi, yeoman-generator, custom-functions-excel

I have created a Excel Custom Function JS add-in by using Yeoman generator for Office Add-ins.

I have followed the template and tried to add one more custom functions in the ./src/functions/functions.js file.

The added function comes from a dll hence I need require('ffi') first in the function.js or import. However, when I build and start testing the functions in Excel, I got #value error and the error message in the debug log shows:

```
Verbose Runtime [Console] [Log] I'm `fs` modules
```

or
Verbose Runtime [Console] [Log] Unexpected CustomFunctions [Execution] [End] [Failure]
[ExceptionThrown] Function=JSCALL1 TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method
'captureStackTrace' {}

I tried including ffi in the webpack.ProvidePlugin to make it globally available so I don't need to require, but this doesnt work.

Comment: Custom function doesn't support to call function from dll. The function can be run cross platforms (Windows Mac, Online) and dll cannot be used in some of them. Could you add the function using js?